# Window not taking into account dynamic vue elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vuejs2

I'm trying to make my page scroll to a specific comment when that comment is passed as a prop to my component.

I'm currently trying to bug fix why it is not scrolling correctly to the specific comment and I think I've narrowed down the issue to be an issue with the document scroll height not being adjusted for some dynamically shown elements.

These elements are shown by using `v-show` and I'm thinking this as if I run

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
    window.scrollTo({ top: document.body.scrollHeight, behavior: 'smooth' });
});
```

that should theoretically scroll to the bottom of the window, but it only scrolls down to where the bottom of the window would be if the dynamically shown dropdown wasn't visible.

I've also tried wrapping the dynamic elements in `v-if` attributes instead but that makes no difference. I need to use `v-show` for the elements as they are dropdown options

For reference, here is the component I am trying to run all of this in

```
<template>
    <div class="w-8/12 rounded overflow-hidden elevation-10 px-4 py-4 pt-3 m-2">
        <ul class="flex mb-0 list-none flex-wrap pt-3 pb-4 flex-row justify-between space-x-2">
            <li class="flex-auto text-center">
                <a
                    class="text-xs font-bold uppercase px-5 py-3 shadow-lg rounded block leading-normal cursor-pointer hover:text-white hover:bg-blue-600"
                    @click="changeTab(1)"
                    :class="{'text-blue-600 bg-white': tab !== 1, 'text-white bg-blue-600': tab === 1}"
                >
                    <i class="fad fa-camera"></i> Post
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="flex-auto text-center">
                <a
                    class="text-xs font-bold uppercase px-5 py-3 shadow-lg rounded block leading-normal cursor-pointer hover:text-white hover:bg-blue-600"
                    @click="changeTab(3)"
                    :class="{'text-blue-600 bg-white': tab !== 3, 'text-white bg-blue-600': tab === 3}"
                >
                    <i class="fad fa-cogs"></i> Options
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div :class="{'hidden': tab !== 1, 'block': tab === 1}">
            <div class="pt-4 pb-2 flex justify-between">
                <p
                    class="text-gray-700 text-base"
                    v-html="$options.filters.getHashtag(post.caption)"
                ></p>
                <div>
                    <button
                        @click="like"
                        class="focus:outline-none"
                    ><i
                            class="fad fa-thumbs-up mr-1"
                            :class="{'text-blue-600': liked}"
                        ></i></button><span class="inline-block text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2">{{likes}}</span>
                    <button
                        @click="toggleComments"
                        class="focus:outline-none"
                    >
                        <i class="fad fa-comments-alt px-2"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex justify-end mb-2">
                <button
                    class="inline-block text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 focus:outline-none"
                    @click="toggleComments"
                >{{comments.length}} Comments</button>
            </div>
            <transition
                enter-active-class="transition ease-out duration-100 transform"
                enter-class="opacity-0 scale-95"
                enter-to-class="opacity-100 scale-100"
                leave-active-class="transition ease-in duration-75 transform"
                leave-class="opacity-100 scale-100"
                leave-to-class="opacity-0 scale-95"
            >
                <div>
                    <div
                        v-if="comments.length > 0"
                    >
                        <div
                            v-show="commentDropdown && !moreComments"
                            class="border-t"
                        >
                            <button
                                @click="toggleMoreComments"
                                class="focus:outline-none mt-2"
                            >
                                Show More <i class="fad fa-chevron-down"></i>
                            </button>
                            <div
                                v-for="(comment) in comments.slice(comments.length - 3, comments.length)"
                                :ref="comment.id"
                                :key="comment.id"
                                class="py-2"
                            >
                                <comment
                                    :comment="comment"
                                    :post="post"
                                    @deleteComment="removeComment"
                                    @commentReply="replyToComment"
                                ></comment>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div
                            class="border-t"
                            v-show="commentDropdown && moreComments"
                        >
                            <button
                                @click="toggleMoreComments"
                                class="focus:outline-none mt-2"
                            >
                                Show Less <i class="fad fa-chevron-up"></i>
                            </button>
                            <div
                                v-for="(comment) in comments"
                                :ref="comment.id"
                                :key="comment.id"
                                class="py-2"
                            >
                                <comment
                                    :comment="comment"
                                    :post="post"
                                    @deleteComment="removeComment"
                                    @commentReply="replyToComment"
                                ></comment>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div
                        class="flex items-center w-full"
                        v-if=$page.user
                    >
                        <div class="flex-shrink-0 h-10 w-10">
                            <img
                                class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full"
                                :src="$page.user.profile_photo_url"
                                :alt="$page.user.username"
                            >
                        </div>
                        <div class="ml-4 w-full">
                            <input
                                class="form-input mt-1 block w-full"
                                placeholder="Enter a comment"
                                v-model="comment"
                                @keyup.enter="submitComment"
                                ref="commentInput"
                            >
                            <div v-if="replying">
                                <small>Replying to {{replying.user.username}}'s comment</small>
                                <small
                                    class="text-red-600 cursor-pointer hover:text-red-400"
                                    @click="stopReplying"
                                ><i class="fad fa-times"></i></small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div
                        class="flex items-center w-full"
                        v-else
                    >
                        <p>
                            You must be logged in to add a comment, either <inertia-link
                                :href="$route('login')"
                                class="underline font-semibold text-blue-600 hover:text-blue-400"
                            > sign in</inertia-link> or <inertia-link
                                :href="$route('register')"
                                class="underline font-semibold text-blue-600 hover:text-blue-400"
                            > register</inertia-link>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </transition>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Comment from "@/Includes/Comment";
import _ from "lodash";
export default {
    props: {
        post: Object,
        scrollComment: {
            type: String,
            default: null
        }
    },
    components: {
        Comment,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            vfTransitions: ["swipe"],
            tab: 1,
            liked: this.post.is_liked,
            likes: this.post.likes.length,
            commentDropdown: false,
            comments: this.post.comments,
            comment: "",
            moreComments: false,
            replying: "",
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        if (this.scrollComment != null) {
            this.commentDropdown = true;
            var index = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < this.comments.length; i++) {
                const comment = this.comments[i];
                if (comment.id == this.scrollComment) {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (index < (this.comments.length - 3)) {
                this.moreComments = true;
            }

            this.$nextTick(() => {
                window.scrollTo({ top: document.body.scrollHeight, behavior: 'smooth' });
            });
        }
    },
    methods: {
        changeTab(number) {
            this.tab = number;
        },
        like() {
            if (this.$page.user) {
                if (this.liked) {
                    this.liked = false;
                    this.likes -= 1;
                    this.$http.delete(`/posts/${this.post.id}/like`);
                } else {
                    this.liked = true;
                    this.likes += 1;
                    this.$http.post(`/posts/${this.post.id}/like`);
                }
            } else {
                this.$inertia.visit("/login");
            }
        },
        toggleComments() {
            this.commentDropdown = !this.commentDropdown;
        },
        showComments() {
            this.commentDropdown = true;
        },
        submitComment() {
            var comment = {
                user: this.$page.user,
                comment: this.comment,
                created_at: moment(),
            };
            if (this.replying == "") {
                this.$http
                    .post(`/posts/${this.post.id}/comments`, {
                        comment: this.comment,
                    })
                    .then((res) => {
                        this.comments.push(res.data);
                    });
            } else {
                this.$http
                    .post(`/posts/${this.post.id}/comments`, {
                        comment: this.comment,
                        replying: true,
                        parent: this.replying
                    })
                    .then((res) => {
                        this.$emit('createdReply', {
                            parent_id: this.replying.id,
                            comment: res.data
                        });
                        this.replying = "";
                    });
            }
            this.comment = "";
        },
        removeComment(comment) {
            this.comments = _.remove(this.comments, function (n) {
                return n.id !== comment.id;
            });
        },
        toggleMoreComments() {
            this.moreComments = !this.moreComments;
        },
        replyToComment(comment) {
            this.replying = comment;
            this.$refs.commentInput.focus();
        },
        stopReplying() {
            this.replying = "";
        },
    },
    filters: {
        getHashtag: function (value) {
            if (!value) return "";
            value = value.toString();
            value = value.replace(
                /#\w+/gm,
                '<a href="/hashtags?=$&" class="font-bold underline text-blue-600 hover:text-blue-400">$&</a>'
            );
            return value;
        },
        getTimeAgo: function (value) {
            if (!value) return "";
            return moment(value).fromNow();
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Are you doing the scroll *before* dynamic elements are shown, thus increasing the page height and moving the scroll offset off?

Comment: @DecadeMoon no, the dynamic elements are shown and the scroll is within a `this.$nextTick` method and that method is run within the `mounted` method, all the dynamic elements are set within the data object

Comment: Does [this demonstrate](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-mcclintock-0g3ij?file=/src/App.vue)  what you're looking for?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter Thats what should happen when I run the above code but what I'm getting is the page scrolling to about half of the full height, which (as previously mentioned) is probably because if the dynamic elements I have

Comment: You'll notice a computed property is used to limit the number of list elements being rendered without any use of `v-show` or `v-if` in the template which gives the correct `scrollHeight`.

Comment: The issue I've got is my elements rendered using `v-show` are dropdowns so I'm not sure of another way around it

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by wrapping everything within a `requestAnimationFrame` function like this

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    window.scrollTo({ top: document.body.scrollHeight, behavior: 'smooth' });
});
```